# Check if a file exists in Zig

Tags: zig

What is the easiest way to check if a file exists in zig?

As part of my build process, I need to avoid writing over a file if it already exists.

I have seen `std.fs.access` but I'm not sure if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the `std.fs.Dir.access` is the one you should use. But for your case, you might want to create the file with the `exclusive=true` flag and handle the `PathAlreadyExists` error as recommended in the `std.fs.Dir.access` [documentation](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:fs.Dir.access):

> Be careful of Time-Of-Check-Time-Of-Use race conditions when using this function. For example, instead of testing if a file exists and then opening it, just open it and handle the error for file not found.

For example:

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    try write_cache_file();
}

fn write_cache_file() !void {
    var file = std.fs.cwd().createFile("file.tmp", .{ .exclusive = true }) catch |e|
        switch (e) {
            error.PathAlreadyExists => {
                std.log.info("already exists", .{});
                return;
            },
            else => return e,
        };
    defer file.close();
    std.log.info("write file here", .{});
}
```

This prints:

```
$ zig build run
info: write file here

$ zig build run
info: already exists
```

Comment: I don't really want to open the file. The idea is `if(!fileExists(filePath)) continueTheBuildProcess_and_copyTheResultingFile(filePath)`. Should I go with the `access` approach then?

Comment: @tuket yes. What else do you have in mind?

Comment: That's all, just wanted to be sure. Thank you!